# See the creator of an image file

Tags: windows, macos, images, adobe-photoshop, gimp

I hope this question fits on this stack exchange, if not I am sorry.

I was wondering whether it is possible to see who the creator of a certain image file is. 
As an example lets say I have created an image(PNG,JPG etc...) through Photoshop or GIMP, would another person of whom I have sent the image file, then be able to check that I am the creator? Like if they check certain data of the image by "taking it apart" and then get information regarding the creator of the image, maybe the name of the PC or alike.

Comment: This is called metadata. For jpg there is EXIF that may include it. The operating system may also have it.

Comment: @cde I appreciate the answer, when you say that for jpg there is something called EXIF, does that mean it isn't possible for png? Also when you say it might be on the operating system, I assume you mean the operating system of the creator and not the receiver right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specifics for png. And yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPEG and PNG have a "Comment" header and JPEG (and perhaps PNG) support EXIF/ICMP metadata. If you create the image from scratch (this can mean creating an empty image, and pasting another image over it) there won't be anything to identify the author in it (unless you have set a default image comment)(this is true for Gimp, I don't know what PS does by default).

In the general case it is hard to prove that you are (or are not) the author of an image because all the metadata can be very simply forged/cleaned.

Comment: your answer is much appreciated. When you say the "comment" on the image if GIMP is used, I assume when I check the data of my image and it says "comment: created with GIMP" that is what you mean right?

Comment: No, the comment can be arbitrary text. Created with gimp is just one of them.

Comment: @cde alright, but lets say I use the "strings" command in the Linux command prompt or an app like ExifTool. And it doesn't show creator or the computer name but just says "created with GIMP" does that mean the creator info is nowhere to be found?

Comment: @Covítom32 Yes. At least with Gimp. Proprietary software could be fingerprintiing the image unbeknownst to the author. But that's easy to check: create the very same picture on two computers (or at least using two different userids) using the same release of the software and see if the files are identical...